# How should ambiguous questions with ambiguous answers be handled?

Tags: discussion, questions, moderation

In this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45230503/create-two-column-array-from-one-column-array-using-delimiter-in-js/45230685?noredirect=1#comment77428768_45230685) the op stated there was an array of data in this format:

```
[Lat,Lon]
[Lat,Lon]
[Lat,Lon]
```

But wanted it in this format:

```
[Lat][Lon]
[Lat][Lon]
[Lat][Lon]
```

When the OP actually had the data as a string like this:

```
'lat1,lon1/lat2,lon2/lat3,lon3'
```

And was having problems splitting it into the first format the OP stated the data wasn't wanted in.

The accepted answer put the data in this format:

```
[["lat1","lon1"],["lat2","lon2"],["lat3","lon3"]]
```

The question is ambiguous and the concern is that readers might read the question looking for an answer on how to turn data from the original format into a multidimensional array.

What should be done with questions like these? Should the be flagged for moderator review? Is it okay to edit the OPs question to clarify what they were asking for so readers aren't confused by the question and the accepted answer?

Comment: Ugh, yet another "make my array look like this other array" that's been asked and answered several hundred times but can't be closed as a dupe because it's a special little snowflake.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it is unclear what a question is asking, vote to close it as unclear what the question is asking.

Answer (score 2):

It shouldn't be flagged for moderator review as it's something that can be handled by the community. Flags are for things that the community can't do.

If the question is good/bad it will be voted accordingly. If you can make it less ambiguous, as long as it doesn't change the OP's intention then go ahead and edit it.

Comment: Though in this case I feel like you can't actually *tell* the OP's intentions, so probably better to just downvote or try and pick through the mire with comments - though I don't expect OP to be too receptive if they've already accepted an answer.